# Very basic Flash/Haxe layout

Tags: flash, coordinates, movieclip, haxe

I have a Haxe class that extends MovieClip:

```
class C extends MovieClip { ...
```

I'd like to know the xy stage coordinates of an instance of C

```
// in class C
public function f() {
    // how to determine xy-coordinates on stage here?
    // ...
}
```

I've tried `y`, `stageY` and `this.y` but no luck. `this.y` is zero however my instace of `C` is not at the top of the stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DisplayObject::localToGlobal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29):

```
public function f() {
    var p:Point = this.localToGlobal(new Point());
    trace(p.x+':'+p.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

did you add your MovieClip to the stage? something like:

```
flash.Lib.current.addChild( new C() );
```